# Laravel - How to get year property of date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a "datetime" field in mysql.

```
$time = "1900-01-01 00:00:00";
```

I cant get only year.
I tried `$time -> year`, but its not good.

> (Trying to get property of non-object)
>   Maybe i need to convert this string to date?

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this in two ways,

---

1 - Define the date filed in the related `model` as,

```
public function getDates()
{
    //define the datetime table column names as below in an array, and you will get the
    //carbon objects for these fields in model objects.

    return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'date_time_field');
}
```

then laravel return a carbon object for these columns, so that you can use like `$time->year`.

---

2- You can create a carbon object and get the year as in Moppo's answer

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time)->year
```

First one make so clean for me, you can decide which way suits you.

Answer (score 17):

In Laravel you can use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to parse the date:

```
$time = "1900-01-01 00:00:00";
$date = new Carbon( $time );
```

Once you get the Carbon object, to get the year you can do:

```
$date->year;
```

Or:

```
$date->format('Y');
```

Answer (score 10):

use PHP's built in methods

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime($dateString));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try out this one

```
$time = date_create("2014-01-01 00:00:00");
echo date_format($time, 'Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Get `year`, `month` and `day` from timestamp date using carbon library in Laravel.

> 1. Get Year

```
$timestemp = "2020-01-01 01:02:03";
$year = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestemp)->year;
```

> 2. Get Month

```
$timestemp = "2020-01-01 01:02:03";
$month = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestemp)->month;
```

> 3. Get day

```
$timestemp = "2020-01-01 01:02:03";
$day = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestemp)->day;
```